# Não conigo ler o array codificada com PHP em json

Tags: php, jquery

Não estou conseguindo no jQuery Ajax ler este *array* codificado com PHP:

```
[{"voo_Cod":"1","voo_CidadeOrigem":"1","voo_CidadeDestino":"2","voo_Data":"2015-07-13 07:00:00","voo_Preco":"200"}]
```

Meu código no jquery,

```
       <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: "dadosJSON.php",
                    // dataType: "json",
                    type: "post",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),//manda os arquivos em linha
                    success: function(d) {
                        alert(d);


        //testa se exista dados
         if(d[0].erro){
         $("h2").html(d[0].erro);
        } else{
        var html = "";     
        // var html =alert(d);
        // executo este laço para ecessar os itens do objeto javaScript
        for($i=0; $i < d.length; $i++){
            html += " <strong>Voo Data e Horario</strong> "+ d[$i].voo_Data;

            html += " <strong>Preco</strong> "+ d[$i].voo_Preco;
        }//fim do laço  

      }//fim do else


        $("body").html(html); 

                });
            });
        });


    </script>
```

Meu código em PHP:

```
 <?php
// header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
require_once("./authSession.php");
require_once("./conf/confBD.php");
include_once("../html/cabecalho_main_Pessoal.html");



$nomeUser = ($_SESSION['nomeUsuario']);
 //teste
//print_r($_POST);// you will get an array of all the values


try{
    $conexao = conn_mysql();
}catch(PDOException $excep){
    echo "Erro!: " . $excep->getMessage() . "\n";
    die();
}


if(!empty($_POST['cidadeOrigem'])){
    $cidOrigem   =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeOrigem']));
    $CidDestino  =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeDestino']));
    //$passageiros =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Passageiros']));
    echo "Contém arquivos";
}else{ echo "Não contém arquivos";}

// Captura os voos disponiveis no banco de dados instrução SQL básica (sem   restrição de nome), 
    $SQLSelect = 'SELECT * FROM voos WHERE voo_CidadeOrigem=? AND   voo_CidadeDestino= ?';

    //prepara a execução da sentença
    $operacao   =  $conexao -> prepare($SQLSelect);

    $pesquisar  =  $operacao -> execute(array($cidOrigem, $CidDestino));

    //$resultados =  $operacao -> fetchAll();//resultado antigo

    $resultados = $operacao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//resultado com array associativo

    // fecha a conexão (os resultados já estão capturados)
    $conexao = null;    



$dados_result = json_encode($resultados);
echo $dados_result;

?>
```

Minha reposta cria um *loop*, com as variáveis indefinidas.

> Voo Data e Horario undefined Preco undefined

Contém arquivos

```
[{"voo_Cod":"1","voo_CidadeOrigem":"1","voo_CidadeDestino":"2","voo_Data":"2015-07-13 07:00:00","voo_Preco":"200"}]
```

No console log, exibe o codigo abaixo

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>SISTEMA DAW TURISMO</title>   

   <script    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/estiloCabecalho.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/estilo_login_teste.css">

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/estilo_cadastro.css">

    <!--! funciona pra agenda lettering-->
   <link href="../css/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet">

   <!-- Importando JavaScript -->
   <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../JS/ajax_Jquery.js"></script>-->




        <script>


       $(function() {
        $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "dadosJSON.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(d) {
                    alert(d);

                    if (console) {
                        console.log(d);
                    }

                    if(d[0] && d[0].erro){
                        $("h2").html(d[0].erro);
                    } else {
                        var html = "", j = d.length;
                        for(var i=0; i < j; i++){
                            html += " <strong>Voo Data e Horario</strong> "+   d[i].voo_Data;

                            html += " <strong>Preco</strong> "+    d[i].voo_Preco;
                        }//else fecha
                   }
                    $("body").html(html); 

                            }
                    });
                });
            });




        </script>



</head>



<body>

    <h1>SISTEMA DAW TURISMO</h1>
<nav id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul>
  <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="./mainPage_Pessoal.php">Home</a>   </li>
  <li><a href="./index.php">Reservas</a></li>
  <li><a href="./alterar_Cadastro.php">Alterar Cadastro</a></li>
  <li><a href="./mainPage_Pessoal.php">Passagens</a></li>
  <li><a href="./hoteis.php">Hotéis</a></li>
   <li><a href="./listarCompras.php">Listar Reservas</a></li>
  <li><a href="./logout.php">Sair</a></li>
  <!-- <li><a href="#">Reservas</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li> -->
</ul>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No JavaScript não tem o $ para pegar o index do Array, pode-se fazer diretamente assim: d[i].voo_Preco, sem o cifrão.

Comment: Obrigado Giancarlo, vou tentar desta maneira.

Comment: Realizei o código sem o cifrão $, mas continuou dando undefined.

Comment: Dê um console.log(d) em vez do alert e diga o que sai no console do browser.

Comment: bfavaretto, continuou dando no browser Voo Data e Horario undefined Preco undefined, realmente eu nao sei. Obrigado

Comment: Olha no console (F12), e mude o alert pra console.log como eu disse.

Comment: bfavaretto, fiz o que vc disse. Fui no console também não acusou nada, continuou dando o loop. Será que pode ser o array do json_encode?

Comment: aqui bro...  troque isso alert(d); por isso  console.log(d);   Mas veja bem, isso não é uma solução .. é apenas para ler melhor o retorno do ajax dentro do debug.. do console do browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem o problema pode talvez ser no PHP, para isto adicione o cabeçalho no seu PHP assim:

dadosJSON.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');

//Resto do seu código PHP abaixo
```

Troque o charset conforme a necessidade

E eu recomendo usar uma boa indentação e sempre usar o `var` quando declarar variaveis, também recomendo sempre setar o `.length` em uma variavel e não dentro do loop e ao invés de `alert` use `console.log` para depurar o código:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: "dadosJSON.php",
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(d) {
                    alert(d);

                    if (console) {
                        console.log(d);
                    }

                    if(d[0] && d[0].erro){
                        $("h2").html(d[0].erro);
                    } else {
                        var html = "", j = d.length;
                        for(var i=0; i < j; i++){
                            html += " <strong>Voo Data e Horario</strong> " + d[i].voo_Data;

                            html += " <strong>Preco</strong> " + d[i].voo_Preco;
                        }
                    }
                    $("body").html(html); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Note que agora o `alert(d)` vai mostrar `[Object object]`

Pra visualizar os dados enviados ao console use as teclas de atalho <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (Mac) ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> (Windows/Linux).

---

## Atualização

Conforme o output do `console.log` o arquivo `dataJSON.php` está retornando o corpo de um HTML.

Não se pode misturar HTML com JSON desta maneira, veja que você adicionou isto:

```
include_once("../html/cabecalho_main_Pessoal.html");
```

O que provavelmente é um HTML, mas a sua resposta tem que ser JSON, misturar HTML com JSON irá fazer com que o interpretador não consiga fazer o "parse" do json, então remova o que não vai usar.

Veja também que as mensagens de erro devem ser json, tente assim:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
require_once("./authSession.php");
require_once("./conf/confBD.php");

$nomeUser = ($_SESSION['nomeUsuario']);
 //teste
//print_r($_POST);// you will get an array of all the values


try{
    $conexao = conn_mysql();
}catch(PDOException $excep){
    echo json_encode(array("Erro!: " . $excep->getMessage() . "\n"));
    die();
}

if(!empty($_POST['cidadeOrigem'])){
    $cidOrigem   =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeOrigem']));
    $CidDestino  =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['cidadeDestino']));
    //$passageiros =  utf8_encode(htmlspecialchars($_POST['Passageiros']));
} else {
   echo json_encode(array("Não contém arquivos"));
   die();
}

// Captura os voos disponíveis no banco de dados instrução SQL básica (sem   restrição de nome), 
    $SQLSelect = 'SELECT * FROM voos WHERE voo_CidadeOrigem=? AND   voo_CidadeDestino= ?';

    //prepara a execução da sentença
    $operacao   =  $conexao -> prepare($SQLSelect);

    $pesquisar  =  $operacao -> execute(array($cidOrigem, $CidDestino));

    //$resultados =  $operacao -> fetchAll();//resultado antigo

    $resultados = $operacao->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//resultado com array associativo

    // fecha a conexão (os resultados já estão capturados)
    $conexao = null;    

$dados_result = json_encode($resultados);
echo $dados_result;
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A Resposta do @Guilherme é plausível, aparentemente é este o problema.
Como ele já pode ter resolvido seu problema, eu reescrevi seu código sem usar o `$.ajax` porque ele não é a melhor solução, eu não entendi muito bem o que seu código faz por completo, mas fiz algo meio semelhante e em `GET`, mas pode modificar pra `POST` se preferir, caso outro dia você queira adaptar ao seus projetos ou se alguém quiser utilizar algo mais limpo em `jQuery`

***HTML:***

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"> </script>
<form id="exemplo">
<input type="submit" value="Simbora" />
</form>
<body>
<h2></h2>
</body>
```

***SCRIPT:***

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        var n = 0;

        var html = "";

            $("form").on("submit", function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                    $.getJSON('dadosJSON.php', function(d) {

                        if(!d.voo_Data){

                            $("h2").html(d.erro);

                        } else {

                            //Buscaria todos os dados da JSON.
                            /*$.each(d, function (k,v) {
                                html += " <strong>"+k+":</strong> "+ v +"<br/>";
                            });*/

                            html += " <strong>Voo Data e Horario</strong> "+ d.voo_Data;

                            html += " <strong>Preco</strong> "+ d.voo_Preco;

                            $("body").html(html); 
                        }
                    });
            });
       });


    </script>
```

***PHP:***

```
<?php 
$data = (object)array("voo_Cod"=>"1",
                      "voo_CidadeOrigem"=>"1",
                      "voo_CidadeDestino"=>"2",
                      "voo_Data"=>"2015-07-13 07:00:00",
                      "voo_Preco"=>"200");

echo json_encode($data);

//Erro 
/*
$erro = (object)array("erro"=>"Houve algum problema");

echo json_encode($erro);*/
```

Comment: Obrigado Cassiano. Na verdade o código é uma  requisicão ao banco de dados, onde resgata os dados em PDO... fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC). Acredito que a dificuldade que estou encontrando é encontrar os dados do json_encode. Vou postar o código em PHP.